# append values dynamically into an long[] array

Tags: java, android

i need some help regarding adding values into an array

for example

```
long[] s = new long[] {0, 1, 2};
```

when i do this i instantiate an array with the values

but how do i append to this to the above array if i have another value of

```
3, 4, 5
```

to make it like this

```
s = new long[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
```

i tried the System.arraycopy function but i am only able to overide the array and when i try to append to it, i get a null pointer exception

Thanks

**SOLUTION**

i used this with a for loop to put in the values once by one

```
        long[] tmp = new long[a.length + x.length];
    System.arraycopy(a, 0, tmp, 0, a.length);
    System.arraycopy(x, 0, tmp, a.length, x.length);
    a=tmp;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can not "append" elements to an array in Java. The length of the array is determined at the point of creation and can't change dynamically.

If you really need a `long[]` the solution is to create a larger array, copy over the elements, and point the reference to the new array, like this:

```
long[] s = new long[] {0, 1, 2};
long[] toAppend = { 3, 4, 5 };

long[] tmp = new long[s.length + toAppend.length];
System.arraycopy(s, 0, tmp, 0, s.length);
System.arraycopy(toAppend, 0, tmp, s.length, toAppend.length);

s = tmp;  // s == { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
```

However, **you probably want to use an `ArrayList<Long>` for this purpose.** In that case you can append elements using the `.add`-method. If you choose this option, it should look something like

```
// Initialize with 0, 1, 2
ArrayList<Long> s = new ArrayList<Long>(Arrays.asList(0L, 1L, 2L));

// Append 3, 4, 5
s.add(3L);
s.add(4L);
s.add(5L);


long[] longArray = new long[s.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < s.size(); i++)
    longArray[i] = s.get(i);
```

Comment: thanks for the help with the arraycopy i am looking at the arraylist option

Comment: mind showing how do i use the arraylist? i need the output to be a long [] so that android vibration function will work

Comment: @aaioobe: I know mobile devices are getting faster and faster, but if the Android API expects a long[] and not a List{Long} it's for a reason: needless wrapping **shall** kill a mobile device's perf/battery/etc.

Comment: You don't need to convert back to an array yourself with a for loop.  Either `long[] longArray = s.toArray();` or `longArray = s.toArray(longArray);` should work.

Answer (score 1):

appending isn't typically the kind of operation you'd do with arrays. I suggest you use `ArrayList` object, see [API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/), which you can always convert back to an array.

Comment: haha the API is anything but mine :) It's the official documentation by Sun/Oracle. It's the first and foremost source of guidance when you're programming in java. Anyways, I hope it works out all fine.

Answer (score 1):

You have created an array of fixed size equals to three, you can't append more. You need to copy to a new array, with new size. See [Arrays class](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28long%5b%5d,%20int%29)

```
    long[] s = new long[] {0L, 1L, 2L};
    long[] l = Arrays.copyOf(s, 6);
    l[3] = 3L;
    l[4] = 4L;
    l[5] = 5L;
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(l));
```

The output is

> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Comment: hmm i might try the ArrayList method as what i have written is only an example i might need to add a few hundred more values into the array

Comment: @benjamin lee great. whatever suits you. You know the options now. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
long[] s = new long[] {0, 1, 2};
long[] s2=new long[]{3, 4, 5};
int len_s= s.length;
s= Arrays.copyOf(s, len_s+s2.length); //extends range arrays 
System.arraycopy(s2,0,s1,len_s,s2.length); // copy three elements from s2 to s begin at s[len_s]; s2.length is number of elements s2.
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a1));
```

output is

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot append values to array dynamically as the memory space is allocated to array object at the time of initializing, it means pre defined consecutive memory location is allocated.Hence we need to use array list because it uses linked list data structure internally and allows you to add/remove/sort easily without wasting any memory space.