# Java append element to primitive array

Tags: java, primitive-types

Is it possible to append elements at the end of a primitive array in Java?
For ex: if `int[] a = new int[10];` is an array. How can i go on appending elements at the end?

**Edit:**
I do not want to use ArrayList for performance reason and want to stay with primitive arrays.

Comment: You can't. Arrays are static in length.

Comment: Use something appropriate from [`Collection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) family.

Comment: What do you mean by "append" ? having them objects one-after-another in memory space ? simply being able to print the members of the array with the additional object ? increase the size of the array and add more elements ? do you want to add elements of different `type` ?

Comment: @Pshemo not only primitives but the OP is referring to them...

Comment: possible duplicate of [append values dynamically into an long\[\] array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144549/append-values-dynamically-into-an-long-array)

Answer (score 7):

A way to make an `Array` more dynamic is to create a method that creates a new longer array and replace the old one with it.

For example.

lets say you have an `int[]` of size 10 and it holds numbers 0 to 9:

```
int[] array = new int[10];
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    array[i] = i;
```

Printing the contents of the array will output: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

Now you can have a method like this:

```
private int[] appendArray(int[] array, int x){
    int[] result = new int[array.length + 1];

    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        result[i] = array[i];

    result[result.length - 1] = x;

    return result;
}
```

and do the following

`array = appendArray(array, 10);`

Now printing the contents of the array will output:
`0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10`

Alternatively you can use an `ArrayList` that is basically doing a similar thing.

Answer (score 3):

Once created, the size of an array in Java is fixed.

If you want to have a dynamically sized storage, you will want to use an `ArrayList`.

The alternative is to create a new (larger) array and copy the contents of the old one, but keep in mind that this will be very expensive in both time and memory:

```
// this is a terrible idea, don't do it
public int[] append(int[] i, int newElement) {
    int[] copy = new int[i.length+1];
    System.arraycopy(i, 0, copy, 0, i.length);
    copy[i.length]= newElement;
    return copy;
}
```

This is effectively what an `ArrayList` is doing for you behind the scenes (albeit more efficiently), so if you're going to be adding very many elements, you'll want to start with a larger `ArrayList` than the default capacity of 10 elements.

Comment: You could also use a Vector, could you not?

Comment: Ahhh somebody used the V… word. Get some stones!

Comment: @MarkusMalkusch lol  [Why not use Vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated)

Comment: @azurefrog sure that is why the link on Why Not use Vectors

Comment: @gtgaxiola Doh! I didn't notice you had posted a link.  I thought you were asking "why not?" :p