# Add an int to an int[] list

Tags: java

I am trying to learn Java and I have a few questions on how to add ints to a list. The assignment asks for a function that requires a `int[]` list to be returned. I found out that `int[]` does not support the `.add()` function.

What I have been doing so far is something like this:

```
/**
 * Return all prime numbers until n
 */
public static int[] primesTo(int n) {
    // New list
    int x     = 0;
    int count = 0;

    // First loop to find the amount of results
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            count = count + 1;
        }
    }

    // We now know the length of the list we need to create
    int[] result = new int[count];

    // First loop to find the amount of results
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            result[x] = i;
            x++;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Naturally, this is really cumbersome. I was wondering whether there was another, prettier way to achieve the same result while still returning an `int[]`.

Comment: `int[]` is'nt a list, it is an array. Maybe read about [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) helps you further.

Comment: you can add all the prime in `List` and later return array by `List#toArray`, this way you can save extra computation which spent for finding count.

Comment: possible duplicate of [append values dynamically into an long\[\] array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5144549/append-values-dynamically-into-an-long-array)

Comment: Don't forget to ser an right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are still learning Java, then this lesson is most likely intended to have you learn how arrays work, especially how inflexible they are. Later on, you will be doing the same thing with a list, or some other collection. If your assignment is to return an int[], and you haven't learned about lists yet, perhaps the goal is for you to do this the hard way first, before learning about more abstract ways of doing the same thing.

Don't discount foundation knowledge though, knowing how to properly use arrays is a valuable skill.

Comment: That seems probable yeah, just wondering whether there was anything I was missing :).

Comment: Not at all, and you asked exactly the right question, being a programmer is all about being as lazy as you can...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have java 8, you can do that in a elegant way, using Stream API.

```
    public static int[] primesTo(int n) {   
        return IntStream.range(2, n+1).filter(YourClass::isPrime).toArray();        
    }
```

It's a good point of java that you should learn, maybe later, when you are more familiar with the language.

Comment: Yeah, I came across a different solution similar to yours: `return result.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();` However, given what we've learned so far I doubt whether this is what the expected answer is. I think Ewald is correct.

Comment: @Diederik yes, I think this too, probably your teacher wants that you know how to increase the size of the array. I suggest you don't use any type of List or Stream.

Answer (score -1):

You should just use a `List`. Add everything you need and then return `list.ToArray()`. In this case it will still return `int[]`

```
/**
 * Return all prime numbers until n
 */
public static int[] primesTo(int n) {
    // We now know the length of the list we need to create
    List<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>();

    // First loop to find the amount of results
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i = i + 1) {
        if(isPrime(i)) {
            result.add(i);
        }
    }

    return result.toArray(new int[result.size()]);
}
```

Comment: No that's not the reason.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't compile: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:  Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object[] to int[]`

Comment: Wait, let me fix it real quick -_-

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method toArray(T[]) in the type List<Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (List<Integer>)`

Comment: It should work... can't test it here. Im at work sorry

Comment: Kevin, would result.toArray not return an Object[] ? Especially since it is declared as an array of Integer OBJECTS

Comment: Possibly, for some odd reason. Ideone didn't even recgonize 'toArray'